# What does the double wildcard (*) on a servlet mapping url-pattern mean?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

I'm wondering what is the difference of using a **single** or **double wildcards** to describe a url-pattern on a servlet mapping.

For example: what is the difference below?

1)

```
<servlet-mapping id="...">
    <servlet-name>BuyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/buy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2)

```
<servlet-mapping id="...">
    <servlet-name>ShopServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/shop/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT:
@Andrew is right, the specification talks about only one wildcard (*).

I double checked my code and noticed that the place where I found double wildcards (**) was in a Spring SimpleUrlHandlerMapping bean.

In that case, it makes sense. As per [the class doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html), it uses [AntPathMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html), which states:

> The mapping matches URLs using the following rules: ? matches one
>   character
>   * matches zero or more characters
>   ** matches zero or more 'directories' in a path

Comment: I think only first `*` will be used as wildcard, and the 2nd `*` is treated as `literal *`. AFAIK, `*` is only treated as wildcard when used besides `/`.

Comment: Where have you seen this usage?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213, the double asterisk can be use in a `<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />` configuration and is defined in Spring's [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Section 11.2 of servlet specification (version 2.5) states the following:

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define
>   mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used
>     for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of
>     the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context
>     path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So I guess the second variant (`**`) doesn't make sense.

P.S. I've just tried to set up such mapping and it seems that only this exact url `/shop/**` will be matched (Tomcat 6.0.32).

Answer (score 9):

The [Servlet specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr315/index.html) itself (Version 3.0, Chapter 12.2) defines only two kinds of *wildcard* mapping:

- If the URL pattern ends with `"/*"`, it matches all requests to the preceding path.
- If the URL pattern starts with `"*."`, it matches all requests to any resource ending with the following extension.

E.g. `"/foo/*"` will match all requests for URLs starting with `http://server/context/foo/` and `"*.jsp"` will match all requests for URL ending with `".jsp"`.

Following the specification, the *empty* string (`""`) and a single slash (`"/"`) have specific meanings. "*All other strings are used for exact matches only*."

Following the specification strictly, your second example is not a wildcard pattern at all, but should only match `"/shop/**"` exactly. Most Servlet containers are however less strict and allow using the `*` wildcard at arbitrary locations or offer even more complex pattern matching options.

Answer (score 4):

No where in specification talking about second case.

As per [servlet specification 12.2](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf)

> A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for 
>   path mapping

```
All other strings are used for exact matches only.
```

As per specification second would be considered for exact match only. It may vary based on server providers.