# Spring not redirecting to html page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is my view resolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

I also have a controller that should return hello.html:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHtmlPage() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When I access localhost:8080 I get an error message:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Now when I change my suffix value to .jsp, then hello.jsp is returned correctly.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

hello.jsp and hello.html are in the same folder. Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

For html you don't need view resolvers. Instead just create a folder in your webapp folder.
Call it `static` for example , then add `<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />` to your xml.

In controller instead of `return "hello";` put `return "static/hello.html";`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16598594/714969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complement to answers of [How to map requests to HTML file in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16598594), I would say that the InternalResourceViewResolver knows how to render JSP or JSP+JSTL views. You could of course use HTML views - even if it makes little sense(*) - by writing a custom ViewResolver that would be able to render plain HTML pages.

(*) Normally, the controller prepares a model that will be used by the view. In a plain HTML view, you cannot use the model. Normally when you try to do that, you actually needs to redirect to a plain HTML page, not use it like a view.

To redirect to the HTML page, you put it out of the WEB-INF folder, in a place accessible as a resource.

But in your particular need, you are trying to display `hello.html` for the root URL. The best way to do it is to put it directly at the root of the web application folder atn declare it in the `welcome-file-list` of the `web.xml` :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```