# spring boot runs but the pages are not accessible

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, sitemesh

When I access my app via browser I get an 404 (Whitelabel Error Page).
After searching around, I think it could be a problem with my sitemesh filter.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean sitemesh() throws Exception {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new MySiteMeshFilter());
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

MySitemeshFilter:

```
protected static class MySiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {    
    protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
        builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/decorators/basic-theme.jsp");
    }       
}
```

What do you think? Thank you!

EDIT:
It could be also possible, that my Security Configuration is the problem:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/error").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers("/register*", "/login", "/lostPassword").anonymous()
                                .antMatchers("/admin","/admin**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                .antMatchers("/user", "/user/**", "/offer/*", "/page", "/page/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "COMPANY_USER", "COMPANY_MASTER", "ADMIN")
                                .antMatchers("/company", "/company/**").hasAnyRole("COMPANY_USER", "COMPANY_MASTER", "ADMIN")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                .and()
                                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").loginProcessingUrl("/security_check")
                                .successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler(this.mongoTemplate));

        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(new MyUserDetailsService(this.mongoTemplate)).passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(256));
    }

}
```

EDIT 2:
The controllers are not resolved. Setting the @ComponentScan "basePackages" attribute helps. The controller-methods are now being executed. But it looks like spring boot cannot find my views(directory) to render the page.

EDIT 3:
This is a part of my logging output. Is there anything unusual? It starts with INFO log (log4j) "starting page" which I put in the method ("/") of my controller. The controller method belonging to the RequestMapping is fired, but I think spring boot cannot find the jsp.

```
2014-12-30 10:20:09.422  INFO 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.l.c.controller.PublicController        : starting page
2014-12-30 10:20:09.426 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2014-12-30 10:20:09.427 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'home'
2014-12-30 10:20:09.427 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2014-12-30 10:20:09.427 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-12-30 10:20:09.433 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'home'
2014-12-30 10:20:09.435 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp]
2014-12-30 10:20:09.436 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp
2014-12-30 10:20:09.446 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp]
2014-12-30 10:20:09.446 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] are [/**]
2014-12-30 10:20:09.446 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] are {}
2014-12-30 10:20:09.447 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@727d5eda]]] and 1 interceptor
2014-12-30 10:20:09.448 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] is: -1
2014-12-30 10:20:09.448 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2014-12-30 10:20:09.448 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2014-12-30 10:20:09.449 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2014-12-30 10:20:09.450 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2014-12-30 10:20:09.451 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2014-12-30 10:20:09.452 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2014-12-30 10:20:09.452 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2014-12-30 10:20:09.453 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2014-12-30 10:20:09.453 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@5dbc9982] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2014-12-30 10:20:09.453 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@5dbc9982] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-12-30 10:20:09.454 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2014-12-30 10:20:09.480 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/favicon.ico]
2014-12-30 10:20:09.481 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/favicon.ico] are [/**/favicon.ico]
2014-12-30 10:20:09.481 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/favicon.ico] are {}
2014-12-30 10:20:09.481 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/favicon.ico] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], class path resource []], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@1742114b]]] and 1 interceptor
2014-12-30 10:20:09.481 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/favicon.ico] is: -1
2014-12-30 10:20:09.490 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2014-12-30 10:20:09.491 DEBUG 5884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

In my application.properties I added:

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: Your security is fine. If it was security related you would get a 403 or 401. Enable debug logging and check your logs for what is going on.

Comment: On start up Spring Boot logs all the http endpoint mappings. Can you see the one you're looking for listed there?

Answer (score 1):

For any of you who stumbled here looking for an answer to '*o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'home'*', Spring has tried and failed to locate a view resolver for 'home'.

If it is pure html you want to serve, you need just return '/home.html' from your controller. Spring will look for this file under /src/main/resources/static and return a response accordingly.

For other ways to resolve views, read this excellent answer, [How to map requests to HTML file in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598594/how-to-map-requests-to-html-file-in-spring-mvc/32628600#32628600)