# How to add HTML files to Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I was trying to add some HTML files to the spring project that I was working on. Initially, the project was working fine with JSP files.

This is the folder structure that I'm following:
/WEB-INF/views/jsp/hello.jsp

Spring web configuration is as follows:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

I tried to replace it with HTML as follows:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/static/html/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

And the request mapping is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myMethod(ModelMap model) {
    return "index";
}
```

Everything is working fine as long as the page is a JSP file. When changed to HTML, it'll start giving errors.

This is the log entry:

> 15-Dec-2016 11:54:57.408 WARNING [http-apr-9999-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/html/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: Please read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598594/how-to-map-requests-to-html-file-in-spring-mvc). Maybe is helpful for you

Comment: The code you are showing is launching hello.html, but in log you are displaying index.html. Do you have index.html file in your folder?

Comment: @Rajashekhar I added the working piece of code by mistake. It's actually index.html. I've edited it in the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Have you change index.jsp to index.html?

Comment: @SanjayPatel Yes, I did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve .html files with Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need the following code in file dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<!-- JSP VIEW RESOLVER -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```