# How to dispatch static html pages who are not in WEB_INF Folder from spring controller

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I want that from my spring controller we can render static html page which are in root-context folder of my application. Like: if person is my root context
/person
   content- it contains mt static html pages.
   js
   css 
   WEB-INF
I was trying to create a custom view resolver, but i didn't get success.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link

[How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

more over the custom view resolver like tiles doesnt support .html files to render,