# servlet-mapping url-patterns static pages and REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets

I am trying to figure out how i am building a restFull Web server that will:

1: Serve a single index.html file when going to /

2: all other URLs will get caught by the controllers in a restful manner
for example:
/invoke1 -> will reach the request mapping of "/invoke1"

**The problem:**

First of all spring dispatcher has some weird fallout with serving html pages (i am not talking about resources and the `<mvc:resources mapping` ) i am talking about serving an html page and not JSP.

i solved this issue by using the default catalina servlet like so:

> ```
> <servlet>
>  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>
>       org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
>     </servlet-class>
>    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>       
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/docs/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

With this code i can serve HTML pages (Even behind security, as long as they are under the /docs/* path), So from here i can do:

> ```
> @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
> public String main() {
>      return "redirect:/docs/index.html";
> }
> ```

But that's not what i want. from here on out the URL on the browser will be displayed as /docs/

What i want to happen is that when the user goes to / he will get the index.html but when he goes to /invoke1 he will reach the spring controller.

This is something i am trying to figure out for some time now. hope you can guide me to the right solution.
Thank you.

Comment: now when the user types in `/`, is your app returning `index.html`?

Comment: yes, but its a redirect to docs/index.html and that is what is presented at the browsers url

Comment: See my answer for forward and not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

1) The easiest solution would be to map Spring to something like `/rest/` and leave `/` for your `index.html`.

2) Another solution, though you did not want it, to wrap your `index.html` up in a JSP and serve it on `/index.html` and define your controller as intended.

3) Or use <[mvc:resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)>. You can serve `.html` from a predefined static directory and simply return in your index controller "static/index.html". cf. this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring) Question.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file you can define one `mvc:view-controller` to handle the redirect URL:

```
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 .....
 xsi:schemaLocation="...
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 ....>

<mvc:view-controller path="/index" view-name="/docs/index.html" />
 ....
</beans>
```

And you can change your `main` method to redirect to `/index`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String main() {
     return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Now when a request is made to `/`, it will come to the `main` method, which will send a redirect request to `/index`. The above mapping will forward a request for `/index` to the static view `index.html`. And `/docs/index.html` will not be present in the browser URL.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 3+ and its resource handling you can just do:

- **map servlet to `/`** - all requests (excluding `*.jsp`) will be handled by Spring
- **configure Spring to [serve your resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)** - (thus the `index.html` will be served by Spring)
- **configure `index.html` as your `<welcome-file>` in web.xml**

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you need to use forward ("forward:/") and not redirect ("redirect:/").