# Spring MVC: Unable to access HTML page via InternalResourceViewResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two files index.html and user.jsp, there location is WebContent/WEB-INF/.

In addition, i am able to access user.jsp with the following code:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usertimepass",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ModelAndView time(){

    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("user");
    System.out.println("returned user");
    return mv;
}
```

However, i am unable to access index.html with the following revamped code:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usertimepass",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ModelAndView time(){

    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("index");
    System.out.println("returned index");
    return mv;
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SampleApp</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please tell me the full path of ModelAndView class which you are using with complete package name?

Comment: are you using the following class:
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

Comment: yes, i am using  org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

Comment: When you say you're unable to access `index.html` - what do you get?

Comment: @Will HTTP status 404, and WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TermBreak/WEB-INF/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: I tested the same scenario on my machine it worked. Please check you must be missing something either html file is not at correct place or name might be not correct.

Comment: @Mudit the location of both the files i.e index.html & user.jsp are WEB-INF/

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml`?

Comment: So just to confirm, using the revamped code, when you make a request for `http://hostname/TermBreak/usertimepass` - you see '404 no mapping for /TermBreak/WEB-INF/index.html'?

Comment: I see  HTTP status 404 in the browser, and  WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TermBreak/WEB-INF/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' in the console.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring, it is a similar question with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in WEB-INF isn't accessible from the outside.  You either need to create two view resolvers or put your index.html at the root of the application.  The way it's setup is one or the other.

Comment: This won't work without changing the `DispatcherServlet`'s `servlet-mapping`.

Comment: True, but if you put a resource handler in it should take care of it. registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/");

Comment: Then that should be in your answer. (You can reply to someone by using `@their-name`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create the folder: /WEB-INF/pages/ and put you jsp files into it
eg. user.jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usertimepass",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ModelAndView time(){

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user");
    return mv;
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Access your view at   PROJECTNAME/usertimepass.htm

Comment: Please explain what you think this will fix.