# Spring view resolver for static HTML pages

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

i have some of the **run time** generated html files which are placed in the

/WEB-INF/Static folder

in my context file i have added the below view resolver

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/static/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"></property>
</bean>
```

and other JSP are resolved by the tiles

But problem is when is give the name of the generated html file Dispatcher servlets gives Warning and view is not resolved

```
08:39:03,389  WARN PageNotFound:1110 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/configserver/WEB-INF/static/page_1.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'config'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i followed this post [How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

these are static content so added

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />
```

and i return the name of the file from the controller method