# Way to map Spring viewresolver to html file

Tags: html, xml, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am doing project on Spring MVC with html file as viewResolver. Already my project done in ftl (freemarker template) files as viewResolver perfectly. But I want to do conversion of all **ftl files into html files**. Hence I have tried hard for two days and do some configuration changes in view resolver like below, but nothing worked.

My original code in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="allowRequestOverride" value="false" />
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="allowSessionOverride" value="false" />
    <property name="exposePathVariables" value="true" />
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc" />
</bean>
```

I have made some changes like below

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

My DispatcherServlet configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My html files are in **"/WEB-INF/views/"** folder. What changes I need to do to run the html files. Any alternate way also warmly welcome. Thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 1):

HTML pages meant for implementing static views, we have great feature in spring to render the static resources like html, css and images i.e.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />
```

Similar question asked here [SpringViewResolver for HTML views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966027/spring-view-resolver-for-static-html-pages)

Answer (score 0):

================================ **SOLUTION** ========================================

### Newly created Folder structure:

```
 WEB-INF
   `-static
          |-html
                `-index.html
```

### Spring config:

```
<resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />

 <beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <beans:property name="prefix" value="" />
 <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</beans:bean>
```

### My web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String homePage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String returnText = "static/html/index";
    return returnText;
}
```

I have searched and implemented various ways. Its now **working like a boss**.
Below link helped me and stiched my time a lot. Also need to work various html files with this solution.

[Spring MVC ViewResolver not mapping to HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980839/spring-mvc-viewresolver-not-mapping-to-html-files)