# Cannot access HTML pages but JSP pages are accessible

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am working on basic spring project and trying to implement custom login page. But when I try to access HTML pages it gives me error "page not found" but my jsp pages are accessible from the same location(i.e ProjectName/webcontent/Sample.jsp). why am I not able to access html pages  ?

web.xml is :-

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
<filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Sample1.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true"  authentication-manager- ref="FormBasedAuthenticationManager" >

<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

</security:http>




<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
<security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
<security:filter-chain pattern="/**"  filters="springSecurityFilterChain" />
</security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>


</beans>
```

sevlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="XYZ" />
<Secured:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you please post your view resolver code to see how you have it configured?

Comment: @Aeseir I have updated it

Comment: so your html fileas are located in the /WEB-INF/ folder and no other subfolder?

Comment: yes they are in WEB-INF

Answer (score 1):

based on the information problem is with view resolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

JSTLView is for JSP.

change it to:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>
```

Great answer to this problem can be found here too: [How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

EDIT 1:
Since HTML is static you can use the following:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

put your HTML files in webapp/static/ folder and when you return the view do the following for e.g.

```
return "index.html";
```

Comment: Even after modifying the bean in above format its not working. Do we need t make any other changes ?

Comment: Also I am using viewResolver for first time previously I used JSP pages and didnt required any resolver. so I want to know why it is required for HTML pages

Comment: from where we need to return "index.html" ?