# Clarification in Spring MVC 3.2 from tiles to thymeleaf

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, apache-tiles

I'm using spring MVC 3.2  with tiles for integration with  jsp pages. My plan is to change jsp to Html pages to make it more responsive.
Which is quite straight forwared to change the viewresolver.

But when i came across this link
[How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)
it seems to quite more simple then using thymeleaf. I was just wondering does it actually work without any any Spring-integrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve html pages without thymeleaf but the contents of the page will be all static. You cannot retrieve values in Spring model since HTML is just HTML. If you need to retrieve values from the server, you need to use ajax calls then do javascript to set/get values to/from the DOM.