# No mapping found for Index.html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

Consider the following `Controller`

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public ModelAndView home() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    return model;
}
```

And this s my `servlet-context.xml`:

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

And this is my `web.xml`:

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Every time I hit the url I get this message:

`Aug 08, 2015 10:59:47 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MeraComputer/WEB-INF/views/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
Aug 08, 2015 10:59:48 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MeraComputer/WEB-INF/views/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'`

My folder structure is also good,I suppose,

[Folder Structure](http://ctrlv.in/617695)

Comment: show the tree structure of your application

Comment: Click the folder structure link.. you will get to see that...

Comment: Might be something with this file `servlet-context.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think static html files won't work as views. The request is being **forwarded** to the view, i.e. to `/MeraComputer/WEB-INF/views/index.html`, and because it's a static file but not a request handler, you may be getting the warning.

Static files should be handled differently. [This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring) a similar post, I think, which could help.

Comment: I changed Html to jsp. And it works like charm.. Thanks.