# How to integrate dynamic HTML5 in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Please tell me how can I call a HTML5 page from my controller using any view resolver.How to integrate dynamic HTML5 in Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

[How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want a way in which I can call a dynamic html5 page that can show some specific/dynamic content based upon the click by user, for example if a user selects among given categories then next html5 page should show the data of this selected category, I cant create new static html5 pages for all the categories.The way you told is best for showing any static html5 page that does not change based upon the user click.

Comment: You will have to achieve that using ajax/jquery.