# HTTP Status 404 - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I just created a sample spring mvc project in spring tool suit (without any modification) and when i am executing it i am getting the output as per index.jsp. But after that i just add one index.html page in view folder and i made following two changes

1. In controller class i added : return 'index';
2. ```
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
   ```

while executing the code after change on Pivotal Server Developer Edition v3.1 i am getting HTTP Status 404 (The requested resource is not available error.)

And as per my knowledge there is no other change required.
Please provide some suggestion.
Thanks in advance

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller

public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "index";
}

}
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.srio.tata" />
```

**web.xml**

contextConfigLocation
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[image: roo-context.xml]

Comment: What is the request mapping of your controller?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Do you have your controller class annotated with @Contoller? Do you see your controller class being registered in the logs at start up? You should post your application configuration file, your full Contoller and your web.xml

Comment: Please find above full code

Comment: Do you have any welcome-file-list tag defined in your root-context.xml? Also do you have index.html file at /WEB-INF/views/ location?

Comment: Abhash@ Please find the image of root-context.xml

Comment: And what about this part: `<beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />`? You are dealing with JSP files as seen on screenshot and suffix is html?

Comment: What is the url you are trying to test and do you have index.html in your '/WEB-INF/views/ folder?'

Answer (score 1):

Did you config viewResolver

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya It's configured. But incorrectly since suffix in his definition is `.html`. It should be `.jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.html` files are *static* and do not require processing by a servlet then it is more efficient, and simpler, to use an [`<mvc:resources/>` mapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources). This requires Spring 3.0.4+.

For example:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

which would *pass through* all requests starting with `/static/` to the `webapp/static/` directory.

So by putting `index.html` in `webapp/static/` and using `return "static/index.html";` from your method, Spring should find the view.

Refer this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480301/4531387

Answer (score 0):

IN web.xml change url pattern from

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>
```