# Spring MVC working with .html

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm just starting with Spring MVC.
Created a default template with IntelliJ, and now I'm trying to add some content.

The default extension for the pages is `.jsp`, but I want to change my pages to `.html` extension and can't figure out how.

So I have `about.jsp` file and I want to change it to `about.html`.
I changed the filename itself and in the file `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`I changed:

```
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
```

To:

```
<property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
```

After my change I get:

> 05-Jul-2016 15:31:25.788 WARNING [http-nio-8082-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/view/pages/about.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

And a page with 404 status.

This my directory tree:

[image: Working dir]

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.weitz.alex"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

**web.xml**:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

**HelloController.java**:

```
package com.weitz.alex;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "about";
    }
}
```

Comment: this will help you. visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring

Answer (score 1):

remove this line `<property name="suffix" value=".html"/>` since html pages are static handle it as a `resource` add these lines to the `configuration`.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/WEB-INF/view/pages/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

there is no need to handle this with a `viewresolver`.

and change your return statement in the controller to this.

`return "redirect:/pages/about.htm";`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like **you're missing a resource mapping for your .html pages**.
Try adding one to your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`.
An example could look like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/WEB-INF/view/pages/" />
```

For a more detailed description of your problem, you might also have a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480301/1391131)** answer, which shows the solution for a very similar problem.

---

I'd also recommend you to change your folder structure and place your files in a folder called `"/static/resources/"` or similar because your .html files are  static (your jsp files weren't).

Your prefix and suffix properties look like they should just work fine.