# How to enter angular4 pages from spring mvc

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, angular5, angular4-router

I have `angular4` + `spring mvc` project here is my project hierarchy

[image]

my `index.html` content

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MonitoringFront</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body></html>
```

and my web Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ge.mvc"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
       public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
          InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
          resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
          resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/monitoringFront");
          return resolver;
       }

}
```

and when I want to enter my pages for example login page which is my default page I `am getting page not fount error` when i am trying to enter `http://localhost:8080/springMvcApp/` url . Did I do something wrong ?

my `router urls` from `angular 4` `app.module.ts` file

```
const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I considere that your problem is equals with this question, because you want to render only de angular application,

[How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

In my point of view you need to split the problems to have a better architecture in one side you need your front end using angular 5 and in the other side spring mvc to create rest services, and also you probably will need JWT for authentication.