# @Controller class is not redirecting to the specified page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-web

This is my Controller class

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @GetMapping(value="/")
    public String homePage() {
        return "index";
    }   
}
```

And I also have a RestController class

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @Autowired
    private AddPostService addPostService;

    @PostMapping("/addpost")
    public boolean processBlogPost(@RequestBody BlogPost blogPost)
    {
        blogPost.setCreatedDate(new java.util.Date());
        addPostService.insertBlogPost(blogPost);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I have included all the necessary packages in the `@ComponentScan` of the Spring Application class.

I tried placing the `index.html` page in both `src/main/resources/static` and `src/main/resources/templates`. But when I load `localhost:8080` it shows `Whitelabel error page`.

While debugging, the control is actually **reaching** `return "index";` , but the page is not displayed.

Comment: what template engine are you using?, please post the pom file here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve .html files with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479213/how-to-serve-html-files-with-spring)

Comment: The "whitelabel error" also means you're getting an informative message on the server console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default view resolver will look in folders called resources, static and public.

So put your index.html in /resources/resources/index.html or /resources/static/index.html or /resources/public/index.html

You also need to return the full path for the file and the extension

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
    @GetMapping(value="/")
    public String homePage() {
        return "/index.html";
    }   
}
```

This makes your html page publicly available (e.g. http://localhost:8080/index.html will serve up the page) If this isn't what you want then you'll need to look at defining a view resolver.

Answer (score 1):

One of the correct behavior is to register your view in configuration and keep it under `src/main/resources/templates/index.html`:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

}
```