# Servlet url mapping for front controller pattern

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to learn spring MVC framework. Dispatcher servlet is suppose to handle all the incoming requests and we achieve that with following configuration :

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My question is how / is different from /*. When we return the view name, we usually prefix / before the view name like /WEB-INF, so will that request also go through DispatcherServlet. If not why?

Comment: Have a look here  
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843294/what-does-the-double-wildcard-on-a-servlet-mapping-url-pattern-mean

Answer (score 2):

In a JAVA EE web application, there are 3 parts to URL mappings:

- Context path (root of your URL)
- Servlet path (pattern that activated your component)
- Info path (The trailing path)

E.g.  Dispatcher mapped to "/myservlet/", with "root" context

GET /root/myservlet/info

- /root        context path
- /myservlet   servlet path
- /info        info path

"**/**" and "**/***" will match any token afterwards, but "**/**" will only match if no explicit mapping for the path is provided (in this case, if there is a servlet mapping for /myservlet/info).

"**/**" becomes the **container default fallback** for the path.

"**/***" **overrides everything** under the path. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern), this is great for Filter mappings.

Comment: Carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern and fix or delete your wrong answer.